# Paste function in loop with dates-R

Tags: r

I want to exract data from multiple webites(Each website refers different dates)

A related part of my code(for 2 dates) is as below:

```
date1<-seq( as.Date("2015-02-01"), by=1, len=2)

for(i in date1)
{
   url2<-"http://www.covers.com/sports/NCAAB/matchups?selectedDate="
   url1<-paste(url2,i,sep="")
}
```

However, url1 returns as:

[1] "http://www.covers.com/sports/NCAAB/matchups?selectedDate=16467"

However, it should return for i=2

[1] "http://www.covers.com/sports/NCAAB/matchups?selectedDate=2015-02-02"

How can I do that in R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that i never has value 2 in this. Add a `print(i`)` to check.

Comment: Are you aware that you can do `paste(url2, date1, sep = "")`?

Comment: Apart from pasting webs, in each loop I am making further calculations. I need to make loops for these calculations at least. Hıwever, I wasn't aware  of that. It is good to learn. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `date1` to character

```
date1<-seq( as.Date("2015-02-01"), by=1, len=2)


for(i in as.character(date1))
{
  url2<-"http://www.covers.com/sports/NCAAB/matchups?selectedDate="
  url1<-paste(url2,i,sep="")
}

url1
#> [1] "http://www.covers.com/sports/NCAAB/matchups?selectedDate=2015-02-02"
```

Answer (score 4):

We don't need a loop for this

```
sprintf("http://www.covers.com/sports/NCAAB/matchups?selectedDate=%s", date1)
#[1] "http://www.covers.com/sports/NCAAB/matchups?selectedDate=2015-02-01"
#[2] "http://www.covers.com/sports/NCAAB/matchups?selectedDate=2015-02-02"
```